# How to calculate scale based on viewport width and kept aspect ratio, with pure CSS?

Tags: css, transform, scale

I have this container with a fixed 16:9 aspect ratio.
In this container I have another container with full width and 7.81% height based on the width. What I would like to achieve is to scale the contents in this container based on the viewport width but with kept aspect ratio.
The base size is 1280px. So if the windows is 640px, the scale would be 0.5.
Calc however, doesn't return a float value. So scale is not working properly with calc. Is there another way to achieve this?

I know this is possible with JavaScript, but I would like to avoid this.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qdc05hqm/

```
<style>
.outer-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 177.78vh;
  background: #cc00cc;
  position:relative;
}

.inner-container {
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7.81vw;
}

.content {
  color: #FFF;
  transform: scale(calc(1280px / 100vw)); <--- Does not work.
}
</style>

<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="content">
      This text and other stuff should be scaled based on the viewport width
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For that you'll need script

Comment: Also seems like you are not allowed to use vw in calc at all.

Comment: Of course you can use `vw` with calc https://jsfiddle.net/ofohyLu2/

Comment: Weird. When I tried in Chrome it changed 100vw to 100 in the calculation. Maybe something else went wrong.

Comment: Yes, when you use `*` and `/` one needs to be a number

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: can you show the solution with JS?

Answer (score -2):

Use

`.content{
       font-size:calc(10px + 0.3vw)
 }`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, bad example. It's not only going to be text. Also buttons and such.

Comment: Use width: vw, where ever you want to scale the size also with min-width and max-width. You can also use responsive media queries.

Comment: Thing is I'm going to have a lot of button tightly together. If I use a dynamic width they might not stay in the exact same place when I resize the browser. Rouding errors and such. That's why I wanted to scale the full content instead.

Comment: First of all in transform scale its not possible to scale for lower screen in other words you can only maximize the size of that particular div using scale  the smallest number you can use in scale property is 1 for which means screen will be to its 100% and if you decrease the number to 0 div will go blank and if you go on to -1, -2.. the div will get upside down and starts maximizing.

Comment: @talha One can use decimal, like `0.5`, so a number can be less than 1